# Error can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

My program is supposed to reverse the string inputted, print it then extract the numbers and print the numbers of the reversed string in a list.

```
def reverse_str(string):
    revstring =('')
    length=len(string)
    i = length - 1
    while i>=0:
        revstring = revstring + string[i]
        i = i - 1
    return revstring
def strip_digits(string):
    result = []
    for c in string:
        result = result + c
string = raw_input("Enter a string->")
new_str = reverse_str(string)
print new_str
numberless_str  = strip_digits(string)
print numberless_str
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the `str` in a `list`

```
result = result + [c]
```

or use `append()`

```
result.append(c)
```

Comment: "Error cannot concatenate 'str' to 'list'". What could this possibly *mean*???

Comment: Or even `result += c` because `__iadd__` accepts any iterable

Comment: @JBernardo: do you mean `result += string`?

Comment: @KeithRandall Doesn't matter. Either a `result += c` inside the loop or `result += string` or `result.extend(string)` or `result = list(string)` will result in the same thing

Answer (score 2):

If you want them as a list, you should change:

```
result = result + c
```

into:

```
result.append (c)
```

However, keep in mind that your code doesn't quite meet you specifications.

Specifically, your function `strip_digits` *isn't* stripping (ie, throwing away) digits, it's actually making a list of them, so I'd rename it to `get_digits`. I'd also change `numberless_str` into `number_str` since it's not numberless at all.

Secondly, it's getting *all* characters from the input string rather than just the digits.

Thirdly, it's acting on the original string rather than the reversed one.

Finally, you should *return* the `result` from your function, otherwise you get nothing (`None`).

The code would be better written as:

```
def reverse_str(string):
    revstring = ''
    length=len (string)
    i = length - 1
    while i >= 0:
        revstring = revstring + string[i]
        i = i - 1
    return revstring

def get_digits(string):
    result = []                    # <- start with empty list.
    for c in string:               # <- check every char
        if c in "1234567890":      # <- but only transfer digits
            result.append (c)      # <- use append for lists
    return result

string = raw_input("Enter a string->")
new_str = reverse_str(string)
print new_str
number_str  = get_digits(new_str)
print number_str
```

Comment: the digits are supposed to be printed in a list

Comment: does it matter? like do i have to change it into that?

Comment: when i changed it i got this error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: @user1695993, that error means (usually) you've initialised `result` to `None`. Check my code in the update.

Comment: thank you sir! I will now be starting the flowchart for this.

Comment: @user1695993, if this is for homework (flowchart seems to indicate this since I haven't seen one in the field for several decades), I would not use that code verbatim since you'll almost certainly be found out for plagiarism (SO is a public site). Instead, use my code to gain an understanding, then re-implement it without looking. That way, you'll end up a much better developer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `strip_digits()` is a work in progress? As written it when it enters the for loop it tries to append a string `c` onto a list `[]`. You can't do that. You can append a string to another string, or a list to another list.

Perhaps you meant `result` to start as an empty string like it does is `reverse_str`?

```
def strip_digits(string):
    result = ''
    for c in string:
        result = result + c
```

Or if you want it to be a list, then put `c` into a list first, or use `append()`:

```
def strip_digits(string):
    result = []
    for c in string:
        result = result + [c]
        # or: result.append(c)
```

Comment: i want it to be into a list, however even after this edit the output say i type in "blah123" it gives me the reverse however it doesnt give me the list